# The Steenrod Algebra of the Dihedral Group $D_{2n}$, $n=0 \pmod{4}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, steenrod-algebra

As the tile suggests, I'm interested in computing the action of the Steenrod Algebra on $H^*(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)$, for $n=0 \pmod{4}$. Let us start with some definitions/facts:
$$D_{2n} = \langle x,y \mid x^n=y^2=1, xyx=y \rangle$$

$$ H^*(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x,y,w]/(xy+x^2)$$
where $|x|=|y|=1$ and $|w|=2$. $w \in H^2(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is the class represented by the standard representation of $D_{2n}\to O(2)$ as the group of symmetries of the regular $n$-gon.

**I need to determine $Sq^1(w)$**.

Using the Bockstein l.e.s. for $Z \to Z \to Z_2$ and $Z_2 \to Z_4 \to Z_2$ I have the following commutative diagram:

[image]

Since on the paper I'm reading it's claimed that $H_2(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\langle w_* \rangle$ and that $H^3(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\langle x^3,y^3,wx,wy\rangle$, my intuition tells me that $Sq^1(w)=wx+wy$. This is just an intuition and I have no idea how to prove it. I think much could be said if one knows the generators of $H_3(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$. I tried looking on [the reference given by the paper](https://books.google.it/books?id=OaP6AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q=dihedral&f=false) . It's mentioned to look at page 38-39 for a proof of all the facts I mentioned above, but I'm not able to see anything useful.

> So here is my question again, how to compute $Sq^1(w) \in H^3(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Thanks for any help and I take this opportunity to wish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year!

**EDIT:** I found out that for group representations $\rho \colon G \to GL_n$ we have that $w_1(\rho)=\det(\rho)$ [See here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869389903098/1-s2.0-0021869389903098-main.pdf?_tid=e412a6a4-ca06-11e6-a73f-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1482604343_3aa8768fce67b6644081832e5194884a). Using this it's easy to see that $w_1(\rho)=y$, where $\rho$ is the representation used for defining $w$. Now using Charles Rezk's comment, one sees that $Sq^1(w)=w\cup y$

Comment: So $w$ is the pullback of  the second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2\in H^2(BO(2),Z_2)$?  Then the "Wu formula" computes Steenrod squares in $H^*(BO(2))$.  I believe in this case $Sq^1(w_2)=w_1w_2+w_3=w_1w_2$ (since $w_3=0$ in $O(2)$).  You didn't characterize $x$ and $y$ enough so that I can say what $w_1$ pulls back to.

Comment: @CharlesRezk Using the iso $H^1 \cong \hom(H_1,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, we can define $x,y$ as the dual of the respective generators of the abelianization of $D_{2n}$. If I'm following your reasoning, everything boils down to prove what is the image of the first SW class of the representation $\rho \colon D_{2n} \to O(2)$ which defines $w$?

Comment: Yes yup yes yup

Comment: @CharlesRezk I think I managed to prove everything. Thanks a lot. Do you mind making your first comment the answer so I can close this question?